# Python Multiline Replace

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to get python to run a PowerShell script over Windows RM, because of the encoding I inject the parameters into the top of the file, however this means I need to remove the existing Param function, I've nearly managed to get the regex working but the "Parameter(Mandatory)" section that is sometimes there is messing up my regex, can someone help me fix it please.

I don't want it to match the word Param that might be elsewhere in the script.

```
......
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$TaskName,
    [Switch]$Debug = $false
)

# Debug
if ($Debug)
```

Python 2.7 command:

> args = re.sub("Param(\s*\r*\n[^)]+)", "", scriptfile.read(), re.M )

Comment: Try `(?s)^\s*Param\(.*?\)$`

Comment: That doesn't appear to work, I'm trying to remove the whole Param section (5 lines) in this example, I did ideally want it to match the start of the line ^Param, but that breaks my regex in the example

Comment: Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/uOSEl8/1) and [here](https://ideone.com/X3Zxgr).

Comment: Perfect that worked, it was my bad I was calling re.sub without the r and had the flags in the wrong position, sorry, been using PHP/BASH since forever I'm still getting used to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?sm)^\s*Param\(.*?\)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uOSEl8/1). This pattern assumes the `)` right-hand match boundary is at the end of a line and `Param` inner lines cannot end with a `)` char.

*Details*:

- `(?sm)` - `re.S` and `re.M` options enabled
- `^` - line start
- `\s*` -zero or more whitespaces
- `Param\(`  - `Param(` string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `$` - end of a line

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/X3Zxgr):

```py
import re
test_str = "Param(\n    [Parameter(Mandatory)]\n    [String]$TaskName,\n    [Switch]$Debug = $false\n)\n\n# Debug\nif ($Debug)\n\nParam(...)"
print (re.sub(r"^\s*Param\(.*?\)$", '', test_str, 0, re.M|re.S))
```

Output is

```py
# Debug
if ($Debug)
```